# How this Recursive JavaScript function is working?

Tags: javascript, recursion, anonymous-function

How the below function is working recursively?

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
 *     this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {TreeNode} root
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {TreeNode}
 */
var searchBST = function(root, val) {
    if(root === null){
        return null;
    }
    else if(root.val === val){
        return root;
    }
    else if(val < root.val){
        return searchBST(root.left, val);
    }
    return searchBST(root.right, val);
};
```

I was writing a JS code to find the node in the BST that the node's value equals the given value. And have to return the subtree rooted with that node. I accidentally run the above code and it worked correctly.

But, I am unable to understand how this recursive function worked. How recursive anonymous function works?

Comment: What about it don't you understand specifically? The function is returning the result of a call to a function called `name`, passing it an argument.

Comment: @deceze , searchBST is the name of a variable and the function is anonymous, so I don't understand how searchBST(root.left, val) worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is getting assigned to `var name`.

```
function name() { ... };
```

is (very nearly) equivalent to

```
var name = function() { ... };
```